# DIfference between MD5,MD4,SHA1,SHA2 algorithms in HASH_BYTES() Function In T-sql

Tags: t-sql

Can any one help me out in understanding what really is the difference between SHA1,SHA2,MD4 and MD5 algorithms in terms of data of  a table.

Which is the precise situation to opt which algorithm. ?

How HASH_BYTES() treats each Algorithm?

Please Help

Thanks n Regards

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing, I just did a search on hashing algorithms a moment ago. :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cryptographic_hash_functions

Comment: Probably this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cryptographic_hash_functions#Compression_function

Comment: I mean I need it in terms of tables and hoe it effects data collisions and all

Comment: You can find and try out collisions of MD4 and MD5 here: http://decrane.io/md4, for SHA1 & 2 there are no known collisions

Answer (score 0):

MD4 and MD5 should not be used at all, both are severely broken. SHA1 is teoretically broken, so its not recommended to use as well. From the mentioned algorithms only SHA2 should be used.

Edit: SHA1 is now proven to be broken by a [practical attack](https://shattered.it/)